# Error: all observations are in the same group, while filtering the R model dynamically from shiny ui list

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Guys i am new to Shiny and here i am facing issue with R to shiny translation, 
i am using SelectInput to give teacher_IDs as input to filter the corresponding students data on sever.r. 
[Data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGuRF.png)
upto here below code works fine.

```
library(shiny)

x <- fluidPage("this is fluid page", 
           selectInput("Selecter","slide to select",choices = ID$Teacher_ID, 
selected = "1003935242" ),
          tableOutput("data")
  ################### server.r #################
)
shinyServer(function(input, output) 
output$data = renderTable({
  TeachersData[TeachersData$Teacher_ID==input$Selecter,]
}) 
})
```

But here below when i add more code that actually calculates statistical values using anova,kruskal etc in RenderTable() block like below, i get error message

---

> Error:All observations are in the same group

***, i tried to resolve by doing split and creating groups with factor and few other things but cant resolve.
there is no problem in the code, it seems problem manipulation of the data with shiny way.

```
   ############ server.r problematic ##########

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$data = renderTable({

  Instro = TeachersData[TeachersData$Teacher_ID==input$Selecter,]
  Data_Procedure1= Instro 
  Data_Procedure1$Score=as.numeric(as.character(Data_Procedure1$Score))
  Data_Procedure1_ByCourse=Subset_Data_ByCourse_fct(Data_Procedure1)
  ANOVA_Procedure1= Compare_ANOVA_Procedure1_fct(Data_Procedure1, 
  Data_Procedure1$Score, as.factor(Data_Procedure1$Course_ID), alpha)
  p_Procedure1 = ANOVA_Procedure1$p_value
  Method_Procedure1= ANOVA_Procedure1$test_name
  PairWise_Compare_Procedure1=Pairwise_Comparison_fct(Method_Procedure1, 
  Data_Procedure1, Data_Procedure1$Score, 
  as.factor(Data_Procedure1$Course_ID ))
  result <- as.data.frame(PairWise_Compare_Procedure1)
})

})
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92Ns9.png)

Please anyone help to figure out, Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Ricardo for helping out, but the problem was something else.
after further digging out, i found that there is problem with the data set. because when i was filtering the data then some Teacher_ID's in data were having single records and no further sub-grouping, that's was statistical model was unable to capture observations of those Teacher_ID's and throwing error of having all observations in the same group. so when after i filtered out this type data that is not statistically significant everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, is this 'ID$Teacher_ID' loading ok? Are the options showing up at the UI? Sometimes this may be a problem.

Secondly, if I understood your problem correctly, you should change this:

```
TeachersData[TeachersData$Teacher_ID==input$slide,]
```

to this:

```
TeachersData[TeachersData$Teacher_ID==input$Selecter,]
```

If that is not the issue, maybe you should show what is input$slide?

Comment: and, by the way, if Teacher_ID is numeric(), you should as.numeric(input$Selecter)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out,  apologize i corrected in the code, it was just mistake while copying code. Yes above test code works fine, 
problem comes when i add other statistical operations like below code and filter result based on the selected input.
but if i remove other data and keep dataset for only single TeacherID then it works and show reuslts but with a complete dataset having all the teacherIDs, it isn't working.

Comment: How is your selectInput allowing you to keep all the IDs? If it is, in fact, letting you do that for multiple IDs, then you should change `TeachersData$Teacher_ID==input$Selecter` to `TeachersData$Teacher_ID%in%input$Selecter`.